# Post request Success is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently sending a post request from a client to the server and once the server sends back its response I check to see if its a success in the client. However, I'm getting an error when checking for success

```
$.post("/getSearchResults", options, function(response) {
    console.log("test");
    console.log("response" + response);

    if(response.status == "success")
```

on this last line I'm getting this error: ReferenceError: success is not defined.

How can I know if the post request was a success (does the server need to set some success variable to true?)

Comment: The code you posted won't throw that error, because you are not referencing the `success` variable anywhere. You might have `response.status == success` (no quotes) in your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to return a variable or anything on the server side.

You can use the Developer Tools using Google Chrome and check the network status:

[Developer Tools - Network](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network-performance/issues)

[HTTP Status Messages](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmessages.asp)

[AJAX JQuery](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/#jqxhr-object)

If you're using a recent version of JQuery, you can use Promise interface:

```
$.post("/getSearchResults", options)
    .done(function(msg){  })
    .fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
        // error handling
    });
```

or you can $.ajax

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/getSearchResults",
  data: data,
  success: function(msg){
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  }
});
```

Comment: @FelixKling Hey Felix, thank you for your feedback! I updated my answer. If you want to edit or add anything please share. Thanks.